# Are there alternate methods to activate Steam CD Keys?

Tags: steam

Just recently (today), I bought a Humble Bundle and I do not have access to a PC with the Steam Client...

Is there any alternate ways to activate the keys I've got from my bundle? Like calling APIs manually or external programs?
(Re-downloading and reinstalling Steam **is NOT** an option)

*Or is it not possible whatsoever?*

---

I remembered the Humble Bundle had automatic key redemption... But it's not there anymore as the key redemption API has been shut off.

Comment: It is not possible without the client. You don't have to activate the games instantly however, I have keys that I have duplicates of that have been on my Humblebundle account for over a year and I can still activate them if I want to. So for whatever reason you are not reinstalling Steam now.. maybe in a year or so you will and then you can add them all. It's not like they'll do you any good in your steam library if you don't have steam installed anyways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aside from the client, you can also activate Steam keys through the Steam store website.

**https://store.steampowered.com/account/registerkey**

At the time of writing, there's no way to get to this page without the direct link, so I suggest bookmarking it.

You can also pre-fill the key like this:

https://store.steampowered.com/account/registerkey?key=AAAAA-BBBBB-CCCCC

Comment: With the [Enhanced Steam](http://www.enhancedsteam.com/) addon, the link is added to the menu bar in the upper-right.  Also it supposedly lets you redeem more than one key at once, but I haven't had luck getting that feature to work.

Answer (score 17):

I just looked it up. I ended up on [this](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5414-TFBN-1352) article.

> Important:
>   Ensure that you are activating your game through the Steam application. The Steam website cannot be used to activate a game. If you have not yet done so, you can download and install the Steam application by clicking on the green "Install Steam Now" button here:
>   http://store.steampowered.com/about/

So no, it's not possible to activate games without using the client.

Comment: This is talking about activating game keys only. Which can only be done on steam.

Comment: @Lyrion But isn't that what the question is about? "Are there alternate methods to activate Steam CD Keys?" Seems like this answers it to me.

Comment: @aytimothy Sure, it's recommended to wait a day or two before accepting answers anyway. Maybe someone has a trick to activate them somehow.

Comment: @Izzo It is just I haven't found anything about that the redeem keys can't be activated by the api anymore. Because I can still do it for my humble bundle keys. But the fact that I haven't bought anything recently, I can't say for sure. Latest purchase and activation via steam api was: 22/12/2014

Comment: @Lyrion Same. I also thought it still works with the API, but I don't activate a lot that way. Been a while since last time, so I just assume the comment that said it doesn't work anymore is true. Even the actual question shows that it's shut down.

Comment: I can confirm that since some months, Humble Bundle keys and keys from other bundle websites can't be activated through the api anymore and give you a key instead. Also, there's no other way to activate keys and this is intended by Steam. EDIT: Found [an article on this topic](http://www.vg247.com/2015/01/13/your-humble-bundle-keys-will-no-longer-be-automatically-redeemed-through-steam), there's a date, too: affects purchases made after January 12, 2015

Comment: I'm having no luck on finding alternate methods, so I'm accepting this 'no', unless a 'yes' answer comes up (which is very improbable).

Comment: @schnaader - Great link.  Very unfortunate, but good to know.  I'd been wondering how that worked, and I'd have wondered even more when it stopped working...

Answer (score -6):

You could download the steam app to a smartphone or tablet and redeem from that device. Make sure you are logged into the correct account.

Comment: Can you actually redeem from their mobile app?  I didn't see a place to do that the last time I looked, several months ago.

Comment: No, redeeming from the app is not possible.